# Why is this symmetric rank one update "the symmetric solution that is closest?"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization, hessian-matrix

Trying to understand [symmetric rank one updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_rank-one) and there is this like in the Wikipedia page that says...

> A twice continuously differentiable function $x\mapsto f(x)$ has a
> gradient ($\nabla f$) and Hessian matrix $B$: The function $f$ has an
> expansion as a Taylor series at $x_{0}$, which can be truncated
>
> $$ f(x_{0}+\Delta x)\approx f(x_{0})+\nabla f(x_{0})^{T}\Delta
> > x+{\frac {1}{2}}\Delta x^{T}{B}\Delta x $$
>
> its gradient has a Taylor-series approximation also
>
> $$\nabla f(x_{0}+\Delta x)\approx \nabla f(x_{0})+B\Delta x $$
>
> which is used to update $B$. The above secant-equation need not have a
> unique solution $B$. The SR1 formula computes (via an update of rank 1) the symmetric solution that is closest to the current  approximate-value $B_{k}$:
>
> $$ B_{k+1}=B_{k}+{\frac {(y_{k}-B_{k}\Delta x_{k})(y_{k}-B_{k}\Delta x_{k})^{T}}{(y_{k}-B_{k}\Delta x_{k})^{T}\Delta x_{k}}} $$

**Question**

Why is the last formula above "the symmetric solution that is closest to the current approximate value $B$?

I can trivially see that the solution is symmetric, but  how do we justify constructing it like this and why does $(y_{k}-B_{k}\Delta x_{k})^{T}$ suddenly appear in the denominator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approximate matrix updates as follows:
$$ B_{k+1}=B_{k}+\Delta B_{k}. $$

Note that we expect $B_{k}=\nabla^{2}f(x_{k})^{-1}, B_{k+1}=\nabla^{2}f(x_{k+1})^{-1}$. Then we have
$$ \Delta B_{k}\approx \nabla^{2}f(x_{k+1})^{-1}-\nabla^{2}f(x_{k})^{-1}. $$

Since $\nabla^{2}f(x_{k+1})^{-1}$ and $\nabla^{2}f(x_{k})^{-1}$ are symmetric matrices, $\Delta B_{k}$ is supposed to be symmetric. Denote $\Delta B_{k}=\beta u u^{\top}$. Then the update becomes
$$ B_{k+1}=B_{k}+\beta u u^{\top}, $$
where $\beta\in\mathbb{R},u\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then we have
$$ B_{k+1}y_{k}=B_{k}y_{k}+\beta u u^{\top}y_{k} \Rightarrow B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k}=\beta(u^{\top}y_{k})u. $$

Thus $u=(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})/(\beta(u^{\top}y_{k}))$. Denote $r=1/(\beta(u^{\top}y_{k}))\in\mathbb{R}$. Similarly we have $B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k}=\beta u u^{\top}y_{k}$. Then it holds
$$B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k}=\beta r^{2}(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})^{\top}y_{k}.$$

Then we have $\beta r^{2}(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})^{\top}y_{k}=1$. Substituting this into the previous formula, we get
$$B_{k+1}=B_{k}+\frac{(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})^{\top}}{(B_{k+1}y_{k}-B_{k}y_{k})^{\top}y_{k}}.$$

Substitute $B_{k+1}y_{k},y_{k}$ with $y_{k}, \Delta x_{k}$, and you can get the update scheme in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I can follow everything up until the point where you say $\beta r^2 (B_{k+1} y_k - B_k y_k)^\top y_k = 1$, why is this true?

Comment: Oh nvm I see it now. I can follow what is going on with the math. Thanks. Is there any deeper intuition as what is going on geometrically?

Comment: Well, the update is used to approximate the inverse of Hessian matrix. I don't think it makes sense geometrically. _Please let me know if you get it_. Nevertheless, the update is shown to be good, which you can see in this [slide](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F13/lectures/11-QuasiNewton.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the slides. Yes I get it, but I see it as just a dry derivation without "feeling" it, if that makes sense. Usually I find that if I keep reviewing these things I will sooner or later gain some deeper understanding about what is going on. Anyway thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

In this approach, we require the update of the Hessian matrix to be of the form
$$
\mathbf{B}_{k+1}=\mathbf{B}_{k} + \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T
\tag{1}
$$
under the constraint
$$
\mathbf{B}_{k+1} \mathbf{s}_{k}=\mathbf{y}_{k} \tag{2}
$$

Here
$\mathbf{y}_{k}=\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{k}+\mathbf{s}_{k})-
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{k})
$.

Plugging $(1)$ into $(2)$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{B}_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k}+
\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{s}_{k} &=&
\mathbf{y}_{k} \\
(\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{s}_{k}) \mathbf{u}
&=&
\mathbf{y}_{k}-\mathbf{B}_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k}
= \mathbf{e}_k \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
which basically says that we can write
$\mathbf{u}=\alpha\  \mathbf{e}_k$
From the constraint (3), it follows that
$
\alpha^2(\mathbf{e}_k^T\mathbf{s}_{k}) = 1
$

The Hessian update is finally
$$
\mathbf{B}_{k+1}
=\mathbf{B}_{k} + \alpha^2 \mathbf{e_k}\mathbf{e}_k^T
=\mathbf{B}_{k} + \frac{1}{\mathbf{e}_k^T\mathbf{s}_{k}} \mathbf{e_k}\mathbf{e}_k^T
$$
The closeness between $\mathbf{B}_{k+1}$ and $\mathbf{B}_{k}$ does not seem to hold in the derivation of the SR1 update.