# Why is $\mathbf{u}=\alpha\ \mathbf{e}_k$?

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, hessian-matrix

I've read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4361035/637375) to a question about Symmetric Rank Update (SR1).

> In this approach, we require the update of the Hessian matrix to be of
> the form  $$ \mathbf{B}_{k+1}=\mathbf{B}_{k} + \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T
>  \tag{1} $$ under the constraint  $$ \mathbf{B}_{k+1}
>  \mathbf{s}_{k}=\mathbf{y}_{k} \tag{2} $$
> Here $\mathbf{y}_{k}=\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_{k}+\mathbf{s}_{k})- \nabla
>  f(\mathbf{x}_{k}) $.
> Plugging $(1)$ into $(2)$ yields \begin{eqnarray*} \mathbf{B}_{k}
>  \mathbf{s}_{k}+ \mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{s}_{k} &=&
>  \mathbf{y}_{k} \\ (\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{s}_{k}) \mathbf{u} &=&
>  \mathbf{y}_{k}-\mathbf{B}_{k} \mathbf{s}_{k}
>  = \mathbf{e}_k \tag{3} \end{eqnarray*} which basically says that we can write $\mathbf{u}=\alpha\  \mathbf{e}_k$

What I don't understand is why we can write $\textbf{uu}^Ts_k = \textbf{u}^Ts_k\textbf{u}$ and why we can say from that that $\textbf{u}=\alpha \textbf{e}_k$. Could someone add details to this so I can understand?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that $(u^T s_k)$ is a scalar and you can therefore put it in front of $u$.

Comment: @Lelouch I think the $u$ is in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Lelouch so it seems like it really is a scalar.